# cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tbmstdepartment' objects

Tags: django, django-forms

```
from django import forms
from django.db.models import Q
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError
from schdeules.models import tbmsttemplate,tbmstreviewsched,tbtrnrevdepartments,tbtrnrevdesignations,tbmstappraisalsched,tbtrnappraisalreview,tbmstdepartment
class tbmstappraisalschedForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
    """ 
    Override the default clean method to check whether this course has been already inputted.
     """    
        cleaned_data = super(tbmstappraisalschedForm, self).clean()
        #appsched_id = str(self.cleaned_data.get('intAppSchedID'))
        depart_id = self.cleaned_data.get('intDeptID')
        fromdate = str(self.cleaned_data.get('sdtFromDate'))
        todate = str(self.cleaned_data.get('todate'))
        pk=self.instance.pk

        qry = "SELECT intAppSchedID FROM tbMstAppraisalSched WHERE intDeptID ='"+depart_id+"' AND (('"+fromdate+"' BETWEEN  sdtFromDate AND  sdtToDate) OR ('"+todate+"' BETWEEN  sdtFromDate AND sdtToDate))"

        res = tbmstappraisalsched.objects.raw(qry)

        for re in res:
        if(re.intAppSchedID != pk):
            msg = "The slot for selected department and selected dates exists"
            raise ValidationError(msg)
        else:
            return self.cleaned_data
    class Meta:
        model = tbmstappraisalsched
```

the above code is throwing an error:
Exception Value: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'tbmstdepartment' objects

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there a particular reason for using raw SQL?

Comment: we can write complex queries easily know. More ever iam new to django sand python.So i am using raw queries.

Answer (score 0):

Its throwing that error because `depart_id` is an object of the `tbmstdepartment` class; and you are trying to concatenate it in your query.

Do this instead:

```
qry = """
   SELECT
        intAppSchedID
   FROM
        tbMstAppraisalSched
   WHERE
        intDeptID = '{0}'
   AND
        (('{1}' BETWEEN sdtFromDate AND sdtToDate)
   OR
        ('{2}' BETWEEN sdtFromDate and sdtToDate))
"""
res = tbmstappraisalsched.objects.raw(qry.format(depart_id.pk, fromdate, todate))
```

Comment: What version of Python? If its an older branch of 2, try the updated version.

Comment: Hi its working. but if there are no rows return from query then it is raising a TypeError i.e; argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable.

Comment: This is another, separate problem. You need ask a new question.